# Dynamically add control to form in method?

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cview(this, 10, 10);
}       

void Cview(Form a, int x, int y)
{
        Button brefr = new Button();
        brefr.Location = new Point(x, y);
        brefr.Width = 30;
        brefr.Height = 10;
        a.Controls.Add(brefr);

        return ;
}
```

I'm trying to add few controls at runtime, and everything is ok, but when I try to do it in a method, like I've posted above, it won't work. It won't give any errors, but the button never shows, and while debugging I saw it has height and width of -2147483648

Comment: WinForms or WebForms?

Comment: Why the return bool why not void when you have a hard coded true there?

Comment: WinForms and yeah it's a good point, because I was coding something else, but this don't matter anyway..

Comment: Your code works fine. Maybe you miss something?

Comment: Place a breakpoint at `return` line and check whether control ever reaches to that extent. Apparently it should work. The only thing that comes to my mind is that maybe your `Click` event handler is not being called (maybe not wired).

Comment: I don't know it is relative or not but the return statement is usefulness by the way.

Comment: Yes, I have debbuged it line by line before asking, the whole code gets executed

Answer (score 0):

It was working, but I'm adding empty picturebox that somehow overlaps only this control and makes it look like notthing happeneds, I feel stupid now :)
Thank you anyways, I won't mark it as answered..